# Is Erlang message distribution broker-aware?

Tags: erlang

As stated in Erlang's official documentation [Distributed Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html), erlang nodes can communicate ( issue messages ) to other nodes in the same erlang cluster. Therefore it is possible to issue message such as :

```
Nodes A, B, C and D 

A --> B
A --> C
B --> A
C --> B
...
```

Per my question, by "broker-aware", I mean: Can we have a node issue a message to any other node that is available based on a load balancing rule ?

```
A --> [ B or C or D ] 
B --> [ A or C or D ]
...
```

Well, I know it is "possible" to design this, which requires some state management, etc. But are there built-in features for that ? If not, any open-source project someone is aware of that is NOT non-erlang message driven ( overall excluding RabbitMQ, etc as I want a pure erlang message broker) ?

Comment: The built-in message sending is to a specific process, you either give the pid or the registered name+node. This is irrespective of whether you are sending to a local node or to a distributed node.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a library for that, because the problem is very general. Your computation may be CPU bound, memory bound, network bound or use some other resource. Some tasks should be spawned "close to data". For example, when there is lots of data on disk, that would have to transmitted over the network.

The easiest way is to have some central "job manager" and workers asking for jobs. Other option is to have some kind of metric and update it like in [this post on mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-October/070150.html)